# Dart/Flutter - Compare two List<object> check if they have the same value

Tags: json, flutter, dart, contains

I convert my two list dynamic to an object and I am trying to figure it out how can I check if one of the attribute has the same value example id.

```
List list1 = [{"id": 2, "name": "test1"},   {"id": 3, "name": "test3"} ]; 

List list2 = [{"id": 2, "name": "test1"} ];
```

Here's how I convert it to List object

```
var list1Protection = GeneralProtectionListModel.fromJson(list1);
var list2Protection = GeneralProtectionListModel.fromJson(list2);

class GeneralProtectionListModel{
  final List<GeneralProtectionModel> general;
  GeneralProtectionListModel({this.general});

  factory GeneralProtectionListModel.fromJson(List<dynamic> json){
    List<GeneralProtectionModel> general = new List<GeneralProtectionModel>();
     general = json.map((i) => GeneralProtectionModel.fromJson(i)).toList();
    return GeneralProtectionListModel(
      general: general
    );
  }
}

class GeneralProtectionModel{
  final int id;
  final String name;
  GeneralProtectionModel({this.id, this.name});
  factory GeneralProtectionModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json){
    return GeneralProtectionModel(
      id: json['id'],
      name: json['name']
    );
  }
}
```

I don't have any problem on conversion the List dynamic to List GeneralProtectionListModel

after that I am trying to use the 'where' and 'contains' but it throws me an error says that

> The method 'contains' isn't defined for the class
> 'GeneralProtectionListModel'.

> The method 'where' isn't defined for the
> class 'GeneralProtectionListModel'

```
  list1Protection.where((item) => list2Protection.contains(item.id));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

list1Protection and list2Protection are of type GeneralProtectionListModel, which does not implement Iterable interface, thus has no "where" and "contains" methods. This explains why you have errors mentioned in your question.
From implementation I see that GeneralProtectionListModel wraps list with actual contents though - through "general" field.
So the simplest way to echieve what you are tryig to to is to change implementation to

```dart
 list1Protection.general.where((item) => list2Protection.general.contains(item.id));
```

This solution is not perfect though as you expose field "general" outside. So maybe better approach would be to move this implementation to dedicated method GeneralProtectionListModel class itself.

Answer (score 5):

You can use `package:collection/collection.dart` to deeply compare lists/maps/sets/...

```dart
List a;
List b;

if (const DeepCollectionEquality().equals(a, b)) {
  print('a and b are equal')
}
```