# Dart: I want to check if the contents of 2 Lists are the same

Tags: flutter, list, dart, compare

One List is a `List<String>?` and the other is a `List<dynamic>`

I'd prefer not to change these data types. I just want to check if the contents are the same.

If I have a List `[1, 2, 3]` and a List `[1, 2, 3]` the output of a bool should be true

If I have a List `[1, 2, 3]` and a List `[1, 3, 2]` the output of a bool should be true

If I have a List `[1, 2, 4]` and a List `[1, 2, 3]` the output of a bool should be false

Answer (score 1):

I will sort in this case and check equal like

```dart
final e1 = [1, 2, 3]..sort();
final e2 = [1, 3, 2]..sort();

print(e1.equals(e2)); //true
```

Answer (score 1):

I recommend to use [collection package](https://pub.dev/packages/collection)  with 564 like on pub.dev.  to compare lists/maps/sets

i found from here https://stackoverflow.com/a/63633370/12838877

To compare list of integer and list of dynamic

```
import 'package:collection/collection.dart';


List<int> a = [1,2,4,5,6];
List<dynamic> b = [1,2,4,5,6];
List<dynamic> c = [1,4,5,6,2];

bool isEqual = DeepCollectionEquality().equals(a,b);
bool isEqual2 = DeepCollectionEquality().equals(a,c);

print(isEqual);  // result is true without any error
print (isEqual2); // result is false , since its not ordered
```

**UPDATE**

if you want to compare 2 list dynamic unordered you can use code below

```
final unOrderedList = DeepCollectionEquality.unordered().equals(a,c);

print(unOrderedList); // result true
```

since its dynamic list, its also can compare between list that contain int,null, string ,list , etc,

```
List<dynamic> d = [1,"abc",2, null, ["a"], 4]; 
List<dynamic> e = [1,"abc",2, null, ["a"], 4];

final compare2list =  DeepCollectionEquality.unordered().equals(d,e);

print(compare2list); // result true
```

Comment: Thanks but the question is about l2 is `List<dynamic> b = [1, 2, 4, 6, 5]` and which will return false

Comment: This works, But how would I use this if the order of the lists is different? Since one of the Lists can be `null`, I can't use `.sort`

Comment: can you provide empty list on null case

Comment: i just update my answer,
if its help you , please upvote :)
thank you @OnasaFin

Comment: @YeasinSheikh
yes , collection also provide for unorder list. you can use DeepCollectionEquality.unordered().equals

Answer (score 0):

```html
void main() {
  List<int> a = [1, 2, 3];
  List<dynamic> b = [1, 3, 3];


  bool checkSame(List<dynamic> a, List<dynamic> b) {
     var same = true;
    if (a.length != b.length) {
      same = false;
    } else {
      a.forEach((element) {
        if (element.toString() != b[a.indexOf(element)].toString()) {
          same = false;
        }
      });
    }
    return same;
  }
  
  bool val = checkSame(a, b);
  
  print(val);
}
```